# Stanbol and hadoop integration

Tags: hadoop, apache-stanbol

I'm new to Stanbol. Can it be run on Hadoop? I cannot find an example of this.

I assume it can, but before diving into it I want to be sure.

Thanks!

Comment: I have been attempting this, to very little success. But in theory it should be possible.